Suggest appropriate substitute for cable glands
I have a 3.3 mm cable coming from a sensor (3.3 V) and going to an instrument.
I would not like any joints in the path in the form of connectors which could make problems for the sensor if the connection is not good. I have learnt to only trust solder connections where sensors are involved.
I thought I would just make the cable enter the instrument with a cable gland and solder the cable inside. The lowest cable gland I know of is M12, which is for cable diameter 3 mm - 6 mm, the lower limit of which which seems to be too close to my cable dia.
What are my options?
Also, do I need to worry so much? My instrument (and subsequently the sensor) is powered via a dc jack. If a connection problem has to happen it can happen even there.

Cable glands are a fine solution for a cable entering an enclosure, especially if sealing is required. You ask for alternatives, but you don't say why. What's wrong about a cable gland in your application, that made you want to look for alternatives?

@DavideAndrea I cannot find an appropriate size. M12 which i think is the smallest is for cable sizes 3-6mm, but my cable is 3.3mm. It might slip under a little strong force.

Thank you for the clarification. I suggest you rephrase your question accordingly because your actual question wasn't clear to me. Thank you.

Add a cable sleeve to the cable and thus increase the outer diameter to maybe 4.5 mm or so. Plenty of options to choose from including heat-shrink sleeving. The sleeve only needs to be added where the gland is.
